# Picture doesn't show up using css

Tags: html, css

```css
.mylistshowon{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url('images/btn_list_select.png') no-repeat center ;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    float: right;
}

.myimgshowoff{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: url('images/btn_list_select.png') no-repeat center ;
    background-position: -27px 0px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>他的文档</b>
    <span style="height:26px; width:29px; float :right;">
        <a href="javascript:;">  
            <i class="myimgshowoff"></i>                        
        </a>
    </span>
    <span style="height:26px; width:29px; float :right;">
        <a href="javascrpt:;">                     
            <i class="mylistshowon"></i>                     
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="border_right" style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="">浏览量</a></span>
    <span style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="">评分</a></span>
    <span style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="">下载量</a></span>
    <span style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="">最新</a></span>
</div>
```

The problem here the first and second span doesn't show the picture which I cut it in css `.myimgshowoff` and `.mylistshowon`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add absolute paths to your snippet, otherwise there's no way for these images to show up here.

Comment: Make them `inline-block` instead of `inline`

Comment: i have already try it. but doesn't work

Comment: [It works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/yLnxyd7u/). Make sure the URL to the image is correct.

Comment: yes. you are right! it's my url to the image. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using external style sheet? If you are using external stlyesheet. Try this code.

```
background: url('../images/btn_list_select.png') no-repeat center ;
```